# MATLAB sorting two vectors by value

Tags: matlab, vector

This is a fairly simple task I want to perform, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. I've tried sortrows, reshaping, and other solutions, but none of them do exactly what I want.

Essentially, I have two vectors from the same range of values, of unequal lengths. Some of the values are equal, some are not. E.g.

```
A = [1 5 20 30 53 70 92]
B = [2 3 4 16 20 30 60 95 100]
```

What I want to do is add "NaNs" to each vector to "stand in" for the values in the other vector that aren't shared. So, I want them to look like:

```
A = [1 NaN NaN NaN 5 NaN 20 30 53 NaN 70 92 NaN NaN]
B = [NaN 2 3 4 NaN 16 20 30 NaN 60 NaN NaN 95 100]
```

Some method by which the vector will have placeholders for the value of the other vector.

Do I combine the vectors, sort it, then somehow search and replace all values from the other vector with NaNs? That seems like a bit of a clunky solution, though not impossible. I feel like there is some more elegant way to accomplish this that I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution using a simple map:

```
A = [1 5 20 30 53 70 92]
B = [2 3 4 16 20 30 60 95 100]

% map all A and B elements
% use 1 for A and 2 for B
map = zeros(max([A,B]),1);
map(A) = 1;
map(B) = bitor(map(B), 2);

% find the values present in either A, or B
[~,~,j] = find(map);
AA = nan(size(j));
BB = nan(size(j));
AA(bitand(j,1)~=0) = A;
BB(bitand(j,2)~=0) = B;
```

Comparison with Rodys solution shows this method is a bit faster:

```
A = unique(randi(10000, 1000, 1));
B = unique(randi(10000, 1000, 1));

tic;
for i=1:1000
    map=zeros(10000,1);
    map(A) = 1;
    map(B) = bitor(map(B), 2);
    [~,~,j] = find(map);
    AA = nan(size(j));
    BB = nan(size(j));
    AA(bitand(j,1)~=0) = A;
    BB(bitand(j,2)~=0) = B;
end
toc


tic
for i=1:1000
    C = union(A,B);
    Ap = NaN(size(C));   
    Ap(ismember(C,A)) = A;
    Bp = NaN(size(C));   
    Bp(ismember(C,B)) = B;
end
toc

isequalwithequalnans(BB, Bp)
isequalwithequalnans(AA, Ap)

Elapsed time is 0.283828 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.457204 seconds.

ans =
 1

ans =
 1
```

Comment: This gives me an error at "[~,~,j] = find(map);". Tells me it is invalid syntax.

Comment: @RyanSimmons interesting. what matlab version do you have?

Comment: The computer I am currently on has 7.6.0(R2008a). Though I have a newer version on my normal work computer. In any case, I just replaced the tildes with a couple of arbitrary variable values and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanSimmons However, it also does not accept duplicate entries in A and B vectors. That's why I use `unique` to generate the test data.. And I see no simple way to go around this in neither of the methods.

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's one way:

```
% union of sets A and B
C = union(A,B);

% initialize new sets, check membership, and 
% assign old values when applicable
Ap = NaN(size(C));   Ap(ismember(C,A)) = A;
Bp = NaN(size(C));   Bp(ismember(C,B)) = B;
```

Note that `union` gets rid of repititions. In case you want to *keep* all repetitions, use a manual `sort` and the second output of `ismember`:

```
% combine and sort, KEEPING repetitions
C = sort([A B]);

% initialize new sets, check membership, and 
% assign old values when applicable
Ap = NaN(size(C));         Bp = NaN(size(C));  
[I,Ab] = ismember(C,A);    [I,Bb] = ismember(C,B);
Ap(I) = A(Ab(I));          Bp(I) = B(Bb(I));
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I actually just came across a very similar solution and was about to answer my own question when you posted this. Thanks, though! Yours is a little more elegant than mine, which was nested in for and if loops.

Comment: @angainor: only one way to find out!

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I have bad news for you ;) Although on the other hand you get the points ;)

Comment: Okay, here is a follow up that is confusing me. This code works perfectly fine, unless one of the sets A or B has a repetition. That is, a value that shows up twice. It gives me an error at Ap(ismember(C,A)) = A; "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same." Why? The number of elements in ismember(C,A) and A are NEVER the same, even without the repetition ... what is causing this particular error, and how do I get around it?

Comment: @RyanSimmons *You could use my code ;P* Never mind - my code suffers from the same problem. You can not have duplicates. But you did not say you need them?

Comment: @RyanSimmons I guess you could use Ap(ismember(...)) = unique(A), or do you want those repetitions to appear in Ap?

Comment: I am actually not quite sure whether I want the repetitions or not. I am going to try running the numbers to see what happens with and without the repetitions. Thanks for your help guys! Out of curiosity, if I DID want the repetitions to appear in AP (not that I am sure I do), any ideas as to how?